# Bash variable substitution in Prodigy

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, prodigy

I want to export the results of a [Prodigy](https://prodi.gy/) tagging session through the command [db-out](https://prodi.gy/docs/recipes#db-out). Prodigy is installed in a [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) VM, however, I am not the owner of it and for that reason, what I am attempting, looks like this:

```bash
# Assume `test1` exists
DB_NAME="test1"
#  `super_user` is Prodigy owner's home directory.
sudo runuser -l super_user -c 'python3 -m prodigy db-out "$DB_NAME" > ./"$DB_NAME".jsonl'
```

The previous commands should generate a `test1.jsonl` file, which should be found in the `super_user` home directory; however, no `test1.jsonl` is generated. BTW, when those lines are run, no warning or error is displayed.

Nevertheless, when I directly run the following command:

```bash
sudo runuser -l super_user -c 'python3 -m prodigy db-out test1 > ./test1.jsonl'
```

`test1.jsonl` file is correctly generated, as expected and explained before. Why?

Additional notes / updates:

1. There is no need into explaining what the [runuser](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html) or [db-out](https://prodi.gy/docs/recipes#db-out) commands are doing. I think the error is more related to a (possibly?) wrong variable substitution from my side, that I am not seeing right now.

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single-quotes (and having double-quotes inside the single-quotes doesn't change this). See ["Difference between single and double quotes in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash), especially codeforester's answer.

Comment: Hello Gordon, codeforester's answer worked nicely indeed. I will proceed to answer my query, following codeforester info. Thank you!

Comment: Why `sudo runuser -l super_user` instead of `sudo -u super_user python3 -m prodigy db-out "$DB_NAME" >"$DB_NAME.json"`? Unless you need `super_user` to open the output file, but there are other ways around that (f/e, `| sudo -u super_user tee "$DB_NAME.json" >/dev/null`)

Comment: ...point being, there's a lot less that can go wrong when you don't start a shell as the target account. (If you _need_ the target account's dotfiles, that changes things, but that's a requirement that should be explicitly specified to help drive the choice of implementations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After addressing my attention to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/16706763) (which was kindly suggested by [Gordon Davidson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson?tab=profile), and whose revision is highly suggested), I managed to solve my original issue. The corrected code looks like follows:

```sh
DB_NAME="test1"
sudo runuser -l super_user -c "python3 -m prodigy db-out $DB_NAME > ./$DB_NAME.jsonl"
```

Just to make changes clear, they are:

1. The single quotation marks were replaced by double ones.
2. The inner double quotation marks were discarded.

Afterwards, the script works as it is supposed to be. If I understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/16706763) correctly, there could be some other valid answers; however this one works for now.

Thank you.

Comment: There's security risk here: If you don't control your `DB_NAME` variable closely, contents it contains could be run as a command. (By contrast, in a normal circumstance shell variable expansion can't go through parsing steps other than word-splitting and glob expansion, so any command substitution, redirection, etc. they provide won't be honored).

Comment: Thank you Charles, those commands are usually run "paying a close eye to them" and (as mentioned before in some other answer) always locally, so I don't think security will be a serious issue at the moment. Just curious here: what would be a "safer" approach?

Comment: The cause of the problem is performing substitutions into a string that's later parsed as code. If you switched from `sudo runuser -l super_user -c "..."` to `sudo -u super_user ...`, that would avoid it (albeit with some costs). How to avoid the issues associated with that depends on the details; for example, `sudo -u super_user sh -c '"$@" >"$0"' "./$DB_NAME.json" python3 -m prodigy db-out "$DB_NAME"` is one alternative that still gets you the redirection performed as the target user but without substituting into a shell.

Comment: (whereas if you need `super_user`'s dotfiles, it might be `sudo -u super_user sh -c '. ~/.profile && "$@" >"$0"' ...` or similar; this is back to needing to know why `sh -c` looked like the right tool, and thus how to get whichever specific behaviors drove you to choose it).